# UITapGestureRecognizer Crashes on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uitapgesturerecognizer

My iOS Simulator crashes when I try to use a UITapGestureRecognizer.

This is my Gesture:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer tap = new UITapGestureRecognizer (new NSAction(delegate {
  if(SettingsTapped != null){
     SettingsTapped(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}));
```

I am adding this Gesture to a UIView and then add this view to a UITableViewCell.
The App crashes after touching the View (every time), showing no Exception.

Her is a Output from the Simulator Log File:

```
Nov  4 10:49:47 administorsmini xXxXx[11073]: assertion failed: 13E28 12B411: libsystem_sim_trace.dylib + 19982 [BEE53863-0DEC-33B1-BFFB-8F7AE595CC73]: 0x4
Nov  4 10:49:49 administorsmini xXxXx[11073]: Stacktrace:
Nov  4 10:49:49 administorsmini xXxXx[11073]:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
Nov  4 10:49:49 administorsmini xXxXx[11073]:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <IL 0x000a6, 0xffffffff>
Nov  4 10:49:49 administorsmini xXxXx[11073]:   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],intptr,intptr) [0x00005] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:62
Nov  4 10:49:49 administorsmini xXxXx[11073]:   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x00038] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:46
Nov  4 10:49:49 administorsmini xXxXx[11073]:   at xXxXx.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00008] in /Users/Norman/Desktop/xXxXx/xXxXx/Main.cs:17
Nov  4 10:49:49 administorsmini xXxXx[11073]:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00050, 0xffffffff>
Nov  4 10:49:49 administorsmini xXxXx[11073]: 
Native stacktrace:
Nov  4 10:49:49 administorsmini xXxXx[11073]: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
Nov  4 10:49:49 administorsmini com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.27B5D497-B641-4BCA-8FA0-EF9E28E07143.launchd_sim[10951] (UIKitApplication:com.your-company.xXxXx[0x7041][11073]): Service exited due to signal: Abort trap: 6
Nov  4 10:49:49 administorsmini SpringBoard[10962]: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.your-company.xXxXx[0x7041]' crashed.
Nov  4 10:49:49 administorsmini assertiond[10966]: notify_suspend_pid() failed with error 7
Nov  4 10:49:49 administorsmini assertiond[10966]: assertion failed: 13E28 12B411: assertiond + 11523 [3F572A0B-7E12-378D-AFEE-EA491BAF2C36]: 0x1
```

What can I do now?
I don´t want to Develop on the Device...

EDIT

I ended up by overriding UIView and use its `TouchesBegan()` Method.
There are many approaches to make something clickable but why can´t I just use this one above??

Comment: Have you tried to add tapgesture created with constructor that take selector as argument?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but that unfortunately doesn´t solve my problem, because I need the Gesture with a delegate in the same Context where the Gesture was created.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit of code that I'm using in my application:

```
private void addTapGesture()
{
   imgLogo.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
   var tapGesture = new UITapGestureRecognizer(this, new Selector("ResendTrigger:"));
   tapGesture.NumberOfTapsRequired = 5;
   imgLogo.AddGestureRecognizer(tapGesture);           
}

[Export("ResendTrigger:")]
public void ResendTrigger(UIGestureRecognizer sender)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Triggered");}
}
```

First argument of constructor (this) points to object that contains definition of method with specified Export attribute so if you will define selector and method inside your view NSObject target will be reference of your view if method that you want to call exist for example in cell your cell reference will be the target.
EDIT
Based on comment I assumed that you may be using UITableViewSource . I think your case is similar to mine so try this approach :
Declare event in your UITableSource something like 
`public event EventHandler<DataBaseModels.SavedActions> OnActionSelected;`
Then in getCell assign tap gesture to your view and inside method you will have reference to sender objec, cast it to UIView and retain tag to identify corresponding record

Comment: I tried that now, but I am inside of an StringElement (MonoTouch.Dialog) and apparently I can not use this as target (NSObject). But i am really sure that I did this in the past...

Comment: Ok, this is working (in Simulator) but unpractical, I have to pass a reference to my cell, and I must find a way to determine which one was tapped...
On my device I get an unrecognized selector exception. What is wrong with the NSAction construct for the Gesture?